# Says that module has no attribute that is in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am on Raspbian and running Python 3. When I try to run my program in Thonny or in the raspberry pi terminal I get an error saying

```
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
  import getRoom
AttributeError: module 'getRoom' has no attribute 'currentRoom'
```

I don't know why this is happening as in the code below I have everything that I need to have it function correctly

main.py

```
import getRoom

def getStage(room):
    if room == 'start':
        getRoom.start()

while vars.is_alive:
    cls()
    getStage(getRoom.currentRoom())
```

getRoom.py

```
currentroom = 'start'

def start():
    print("""
Hello User and welcome to Cedrics Adventure!
First Things first what is that you want to
be called?
        """)
    vars.name = input('>')
    cls()
    print("Hello {}, Please press enter to continue".format(vars.name))
    none = input(">")
    vars.currentroom = 'courtyard'
```

There is a class called `vars` that stores `currentRoom`

```
def currentRoom():
    return currentroom
```

Those are just snippets of the entire code which is on https://github.com/FerisJumbo/AdventureGames

I still am confused as to how the module doesn't have the attribute 
`currentroom` eventhough it is defined. I have tried in my `main.py` while loop
to just use `getRoom.currentroom`

Comment: Can you show the definition of your class `vars`? The error is implying that there is no `currentroom` variable that is a part of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRoom.py` imports `main` despite not doing anything with it.  This circular import causes the parsing of `getRoom.py` to end early, meaning that `currentRoom()` is never defined.  Simply change `import main, os, time` in `getRoom.py` to `import os, time`.